# Does $\sum a_i b_i $ converge, if $ \sum a_i^2 , \sum b_i^2 $ converge?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, vector-spaces

I came across a question in linear algebra,
Prove that $W = \{ \langle a_n \rangle \in V : \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_i^2$ is finite } is a vector space, where V is vector space of sequences in R.
Now, I tried to proceed as usual, but got stuck in proving that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty {ab}$ is finite. This question is not from a standard textbook, and hence I am unsure whether the statement is even true.

With some examples, it is easy to see that this statement is definitely true for series of the form $\sum \frac{1}{n^k}, k\in R$. However, whether this extends to all sequences, I am not sure.
If your answer is in the affirmitive, please provide a proof. I did try to prove the statement, but couldn't (Cauchy series doesn't help). I think Cauchy's inequality might help, but I am unsure how to use it(It has been time since I studied it in functional analysis class while in undergraduate class).

Comment: Yes, Cauchy’s inequality will do it.

Comment: Please check that I've correctly made the edits you requested

Comment: Ah, Thanks @HallaSurvivor.

Comment: Try the Cauchy Bunyakovsky Schwarz Bieber inequality.

Comment: And, in future, I recommend to stop using $*$ (`*`). In math, it usually denotes very special things (e.g. convolution), not multiplication. The latter is usually denoted by $\cdot$ (`\cdot`), $\times$ (`\times`), or just by absence of any symbol (which would be my choice in the present case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remembered the inequality in its correct form (credit- Wikipedia). The statement itself is a one-line proof:
$|\langle u,v\rangle|^2 \leq \langle u,u\rangle\cdot\langle v,v\rangle$
I was writing it as $\sum{a_ib_i \leq (\sum a_i)^{1/2}(\sum b_i)^{1/2}}$
Credit : Qiaochu Yuan and Copper.hat in the comments section.

Comment: The credit really goes to Qiaochu Yuan, I just wanted to make sure Justin got inappropriate credit.

Comment: LOL the Bieber jokes just don't stop.